# Prolog Design Pattern to extend module predicates

Tags: object, design-patterns, module, prolog

Imagine we have the `familytree` module below (*simple example*) :

```
:- module(familytree, [         
        father/2,
        mother/2,
        %[...]    
    ]).    

father(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(X,Y).
father(unknown, _) :- male(unknown).

mother(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(X,Y).
mother(unknown, _) :- female(unknown).

sister(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y), X \= Y.

%[... other relation predicates ... ]
```

I want to use this module predicates with different "dbs", for examples with :

```
:- module(familytree_xyz, []).

male(james).
male(fred).
male(mike).

female(betty).
female(sandra).    

parent(james, fred).
parent(betty, fred).
```

Or :

```
:- module(familytree_simpson, []).

male(homer).
male(bart).

female(marge).
female(lisa).

parent(homer, bart).
%[...]
```

---

I need :

- to choose db on **runtime**, not on compilation.
- to use one or more dbs in same time.
- to extend db, for eg. create a “familytree_simpson_extended” db module with other Simpson family members extending “familytree_simpson” db module (see above example)
- to be **swi-prolog** compliant.

For now, I tried to play with `term_expansion/2`, `discontiguous/1`, `multifile/1`, `dynamic/1` and `thread_local/1` directives, but :

- `term_expansion/2` seems only usable on compile time,
- `discontiguous/1`, `multifile/1`, not adapted,
- dynamic dbs in prolog are seen as an “*Evil*” practice, however lot of packages and libraries use its (`pengines`, `broadcast` module,`http` lib, for examples).
- `thread_local/1` is not very documented and seems not often used in prolog source code (swi-prolog).

---

With playing with dynamic predicate, I update previous code as follow :

```
%familytree.pl
:- module(familytree, [
        familytree_cleanup_db/0,
        familytree_use_db/1,
        %[... previous declarations ...]        
    ]).

dynamic male/1, female/1, parent/2.

familytree_cleanup_db :- 
    retractall(male/1), 
    retractall(female/1),
    retractall(parent/2).

familytree_use_db(ModuleName) :- 
    assert(male(X) :- ModuleName:male(X)),
    assert(female(X) :- ModuleName:female(X)),
    assert(parent(X,Y) :- ModuleName:parent(X,Y)).

%[... previous predicates ...]
```

And :

```
%main.pl    
% use familytree tool predicates
:- use_module(familytree).

%load all familytree dbs at compile time.
:- use_module(familytree_xyz).
:- use_module(familytree_simpson).
:- use_module(familytree_simpson_extended).

main_xyz:- 
    familytree_cleanup_db,
    familytree_use_db(familytree_xyz),
    process.        

main_simpson_all :-
    familytree_cleanup_db,
    familytree_use_db(familytree_simpson),
    familytree_use_db(familytree_simpson_extended),
    process.

process :-
    findall(X, father(X,_), Xs),
    write(Xs).
```

And it's ok to use with different db as follow :

```
?- main_simpson_all.
[homer,homer,abraham]
true.
?- main_xyz.
[james]
true.
```

---

**So, sorry for the length of the post. Questions :**

1. What are the criteria, pros/cons to consider with this dynamic predicates solution ? is it a good solution ?
2. What are the best practice / specific *design pattern* for prolog to do that in a clean / robust code ?**
3. What's about using `thread_local/1` instead `dynamic/1`  and encapsulate call to new thread to avoid cleanup db?

Comment: Use Logtalk objects instead of Prolog modules. Define a root object with the predicates you have in `familytree`. Derive from this object the db objects. Take advantage of inheritance to extend the dbs. No need of using dynamic predicates.

Comment: Paulo Moura : Yes, I have seen Logtalk, but GPL licence seems to be a restraint for me, unfortunately (OOP with prolog would have been perfect for my needs ):(

Comment: @PauloMoura : Wow, I just seen Logtalk is now on Apache Licence 2.0 on your website news ! Good point, I will reconsider Logtalk as framework choice. Thanks Paulo Moura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comment, the Logtalk solution is straightforward. First, define a root object with the family relations predicate:

```
:- object(familytree).

    :- public([
        father/2, mother/2,
        sister/2, brother/2
    ]).

    :- public([
        parent/2,
        male/1, female/1
    ]).

    father(Father, Child) :-
        ::male(Father),
        ::parent(Father, Child).

    mother(Mother, Child) :-
        ::female(Mother),
        ::parent(Mother, Child).

    sister(Sister, Child) :-
        ::female(Sister),
        ::parent(Parent, Sister),
        ::parent(Parent, Child),
        Sister \== Child.

    brother(Brother, Child) :-
        ::male(Brother),
        ::parent(Parent, Brother),
        ::parent(Parent, Child),
        Brother \== Child.

:- end_object.
```

Note that the lookup of the definitions of the `male/1`, `female/1`, and `parent/2` starts in *self*, i.e. in the object, the database, that will receive the queries about the family relations. An example, derived from your sample code would be:

```
:- object(simpsons,
    extends(familytree)).

    male(homer).
    male(bart).

    female(marge).
    female(lisa).

    parent(homer, bart).
    parent(homer, lisa).
    parent(marge, bart).
    parent(marge, lisa).

:- end_object.
```

An example query can be:

```
?- simpsons::parent(homer, Child).
Child = bart ;
Child = lisa.
```

You can them as many family databases as you want, load them at the same time, and define specializations of them at will. For example:

```
:- object(simpsons_extended,
    extends(simpsons)).

    male(Male) :-
        ^^male(Male).
    male(abe).
    male(herb).

    female(Male) :-
        ^^female(Male).
    female(gaby).
    female(mona).

    parent(Parent, Child) :-
        ^^parent(Parent, Child).
    parent(abe, homer).
    parent(abe, herb).
    parent(gaby, herb).
    parent(mona, homer).

:- end_object.
```

This solution fulfills all your requirements. SWI-Prolog is one of the supported Prolog compilers. You can install Logtalk using on of its installers. Alternatively, for SWI-Prolog, you can simply type:

```
?- pack_install(logtalk).
```

**Update**

In your comment to this solution, you asked about injecting a database into the family tree object logic. That's easy but it also requires a different approach. First define `familytree` as:

```
:- object(familytree).

    :- public([
        father/2, mother/2,
        sister/2, brother/2
    ]).

    :- public([
        parent/2,
        male/1, female/1
    ]).
    :- multifile([
        parent/2,
        male/1, female/1
    ]).

    father(Father, Child) :-
        male(Father),
        parent(Father, Child).

    mother(Mother, Child) :-
        female(Mother),
        parent(Mother, Child).

    sister(Sister, Child) :-
        female(Sister),
        parent(Parent, Sister),
        parent(Parent, Child),
        Sister \== Child.

    brother(Brother, Child) :-
        male(Brother),
        parent(Parent, Brother),
        parent(Parent, Child),
        Brother \== Child.

:- end_object.
```

Note that is this alternative, we call `male/1`, `female/1`, and `parent/2` as local predicates but they are also declared as multifile predicates. Now we need to "inject" a family database in the `familytree` object:

```
:- category(simpsons).

    :- multifile([
        familytree::male/1,
        familytree::female/1,
        familytree::parent/2    
    ]).

    familytree::male(homer).
    familytree::male(bart).

    familytree::female(marge).
    familytree::female(lisa).

    familytree::parent(homer, bart).
    familytree::parent(homer, lisa).
    familytree::parent(homer, maggie).
    familytree::parent(marge, bart).
    familytree::parent(marge, lisa).
    familytree::parent(marge, maggie).

:- end_category.
```

Usage example (assuming `familytree.lgt` and `simpsons.lgt` files):

```
?- {familytree, simpsons}.
...
yes
```

A couple of sample queries:

```
?- familytree::parent(homer, Child).
Child = bart ;
Child = lisa ;
Child = maggie.

?- familytree::male(Male).
Male = homer ;
Male = bart.

?- familytree::father(Father, Child).
Father = homer,
Child = bart ;
Father = homer,
Child = lisa ;
Father = homer,
Child = maggie ;
false.
```

Comment: I just read logtalk user manual, browse some examples provided with logtalk package and trying inheritance implementation as your example.  Powerful, but I would have preferred separate concerns between familytree logic and dbs, using a pattern as dependency injection, but I don’t know how design with Logtalk (maybe as your delegate DP example?). Goal is to avoid specifying dbname implementation everywhere in code, just « inject » db in familytree once, and use familtrytree everywhere. (Sorry, it’s a bit confused for me).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, as said in my initial answer I need to « to choose db on runtime », it seem complementing categories process only compilation ? (I can’t "decharge" complement and/or add complement on runtime : I mean  passing/changing  a dependency (db) to a dependent object (familytree) that would use it.

Comment: But can you **load** a file with the db at runtime?

Comment: Meanwhile, I changed the solution to one that uses multifile predicates for the db predicates. More familiar to Prolog users and also a bit faster.

Comment: Ok. I imagine to be able to do something like that: `?-familtree::set_db(ObjectXyZ),  familytree::father(Father, Child). ?-familtree::set_db(ObjectSimpsons),  familytree::male(Male).` Maybe it's bad pattern :)

Comment: That's a simple to implement solution. Just define the base predicates like `male/1` as `male(Male) :- db(Obj), Obj::male(Male).`. I.e. make the base predicates simply delegate to the current db object. You can also use a `familytree(DB)` parametric object instead of a `familytree` object and pass the identifier of the db object as the parameter value at query time. The base predicates would then be defined as e.g. `male(Male) :- parameter(1, Obj), Obj::male(Male).`. Then do e.g. `?- familytree(simpsons)::male(Male).`.

Comment: I tried to use parametric object for familytree. But each time I want to call a method/predicate of the familytree object, I have to specify the db as parameter of familytree, pb is the same as with inheritance solution. Maybe I'm confused between Object, Class, Instance in Logtalk paradigm... :(

Comment: Then just use the delegation pattern with a dynamic predicate in the `familytree` object to hold the current db object and a setter predicate e.g. `set_db/1`.

Comment: Yes with delegation pattern or even singleton pattern as http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Singleton#Logtalk, it's Ok ! However, I don't know if it's a good idea to use pattern implemented on dynamic db (robust code, performance, ...). Thanks for ur help.

Comment: In the delegation pattern, the only predicate that would need to be dynamic is the single predicate holding the reference to the current db as you want to change dbs at runtime. I see no reason why the db itself or its predicates should be dynamic. It's not clear what you mean by "pattern implemented on dynamic db". It's also not clear why you're talking about the singleton pattern when you want to be able to choose between several dbs at runtime.

Comment: no, only using dynamic db only for holding family db name in a familytree singleton / delegator object. To avoid extend this discussion here, I created github repo with suggested implementations : https://github.com/koryonik/logtalk-experiments .  I'll try to implement others patterns to play with object composition / dependency in  Logtalk. Feel free to contribute / feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the source database obviously plays an important role in your use case, I suggest to make its dedicated identifier explicit in your definitions, so that it is always clear which family source you are actually referencing:

```
db_male(xyz, james).
db_male(simpsons, bart).

db_female(xyz, betty).
db_female(simpsons, marge).

db_parent_of(xyz, james, fred).
```

So, you basically have the public and multifile `db_male/2`, `db_female/2`, `db_parent_of/3` predicates.

Self-contained modules can extend the existing definitions with their own source knowledge bases, made explicit in the first argument. This is where `term_expansion/2` and the like may help you: Since the database name is the same within each single module, you can write expansion code that augments module-specific definitions of `male/1`, `female/1` etc. with the suitable `db` argument and rewrites this to `db_male/2` etc. Notice that this rewriting need only happen *at compilation time*. At run-time, you can supply any DB you choose as the first argument of these predicates.

It is also obvious how global definitions of `female/1`, `male/1` may look like:

```
male(M) :- db_male(_, M).
```

Notice also that I am using names like `parent_of/2` to make clear which argument is what.

`assertz/1` can be used to dynamically augment each individual database when required, again supplying the name explicitly. However, for clean and robust code, I would do as much as possible at compilation time.

Comment: Thx @mat for your answer. I agree with you, prefer compilation time to ensure a robust code.  However, I see 2 potential constraints with your design : 1/ a performance degradation if `db_male/2` is aggregation of a lot of big family dbs. 2/ all predicate definitions of familytree module using  DBname as first argument can make the code less clean and more complexe to maintain. An idea for this point: use a global var to specify db one time : `b_setval(dbname, xyz)` and `male(M) :- b_getval(dynamo, Db), db_male(Db, M)` but I don’t have idea on b_getval performance effect ..

Comment: Ad (1): Argument indexing will take care of many cases. For other cases, you may need additional indexing structures to answer queries that are still not fast enough, however, you can always build this on top of this separation, and this also holds for other ways to store the data. For larger databases and faster access, check out the ODBC and Berkeley DB bindings. Ad (2): A global variable is a bad idea because it prevents or at least makes it much more complicated for you to reason about two databases at the same time, for example when finding out if any person appears in two databases.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is the use of [Prolog dicts](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/10_docu/05_frequent/07_theories/10_advanced/06_func.html). They have been introduced by SWI-Prolog and since release 1.3.0 they are also available in Jekejeke Prolog. If the receiver is not needed, one can simply use an underscore.

**File simpson.pl:**

```
:- module(simpson, [gender/3, parent/3]).
:- reexport(familytree).
_.gender(homer) := male.
_.gender(bart) := male.
_.gender(marge) := female.
_.gender(lisa) := female.

_.parent(homer) := bart.
_.parent(homer) := lisa.
_.parent(homer) := maggie.
_.parent(marge) := bart.
_.parent(marge) := lisa.
_.parent(marge) := maggie.
```

**File xyz.pl:**

```
:- module(xyz, [gender/3, parent/3]).
:- reexport(familytree).
_.gender(james) := male.
_.gender(fred) := male.
_.gender(mike) := male.
_.gender(betty) := female.
_.gender(sandra) := female.

_.parent(james) := fred.
_.parent(betty) := fred.
```

**File familytree.pl:**

```
:- module(familytree, [father/3]).
M.father(X) := Y :-
    male = M.gender(X),
    Y = M.parent(X).
```

To make the familytree also visible in simpson and xyz use reexport/1. This allows sending a message to simpson or xyz, but nevertheless a method from familytree will be processed. Here is an example run:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.7.19)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- Y = simpson{}.father(X).
Y = bart,
X = homer ;
Y = lisa,
X = homer ;
Y = maggie,
X = homer ;
false.

?- Y = xyz{}.father(X).
Y = fred,
X = james ;
false.
```

The exports of gender/3, parent/3, etc.. will go away with the upcoming release 1.3.1 of Jekejeke Prolog when we have made ('.')/3 call-site aware. But the result for Jekejeke Prolog is the same:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.0
(c) 1985-2018, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- Y = simpson{}.father(X).
Y = bart,
X = homer ;
Y = lisa,
X = homer ;
Y = maggie,
X = homer ;
No

?- Y = xyz{}.father(X).
Y = fred,
X = james ;
No
```

Comment: Analogue to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52580103/502187 , with additional demonstration of non-determinism of function on Prolog dicts.