# Prolog: Difference between overriding predicate and using it

Tags: object, module, prolog

I feel really stupid, and feel like I'm missing something.

I've basically got two files:

- `module.pl` for the universal logic rules (meant to be reusable)
- `state.pl` one for the current scenario

In the module file (`module.pl`) I've declared:

```
inside(Food,Eater,T) :-
    isTime(T),
    injestEvent(InjEvent),
    justAfter(T,InjEvent),
    actorOfEvent(InjEvent, Eater),
    objectOfEvent(InjEvent, Food).
```

Q1) I've had to declare all those other predicates with singleton variables (in the same file), just to stop `module.pl` complaining they don't exist:

```
isTime(_T).
justAfter(_Time,_Event).

actorOfEvent(_Event, _ActorOfEvent).
objectOfEvent(_Event,_ActorOfEvent).
```

Is that right?

Q2) I can't use those predicates like `justAfter/2` my other file without it saying:

> Local definition of user:justAfter/2 overrides weak import from module

How can I *use* the predicates I've imported from my module, rather redefining it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog modules were designed to hide auxiliary predicates. They don't provide a concept of interface that allows separating predicate declarations from predicate definitions. That's why the compiler complains if you export predicates that are not defined. From your description, I assume you tried something like:

```
----- module.pl -----
:- module(module, [
    inside/3, isTime/1, injestEvent/1, justAfter/2, actorOfEvent/2, objectOfEvent/2
]).

inside(Food,Eater,T) :-
    isTime(T),
    injestEvent(InjEvent),
    justAfter(T,InjEvent),
    actorOfEvent(InjEvent, Eater),
    objectOfEvent(InjEvent, Food).
---------------------
```

which results in:

```
?- [module].
ERROR: Exported procedure module:justAfter/2 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure module:isTime/1 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure module:injestEvent/1 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure module:objectOfEvent/2 is not defined
ERROR: Exported procedure module:actorOfEvent/2 is not defined
true.
```

You attempted to workaround this error by adding local definitions. But this just result in the second problem you describe. When you do something like:

```
?- use_module(module).
```

You import **all** the predicates exported by `module`, including those that you want to define in `state.pl`. Therefore, the compiler warns you, when loading `state.pl`, that this file is overriding those predicates. E.g. with:

```
----- state.pl -----
isTime(1).
injestEvent(injEvent).
justAfter(1, injEvent).
actorOfEvent(injEvent, eater).
objectOfEvent(injEvent, food).
--------------------
```

we get:

```
?- [state].
Warning: /Users/pmoura/Desktop/state.pl:1:
    Local definition of user:isTime/1 overrides weak import from module
Warning: /Users/pmoura/Desktop/state.pl:2:
    Local definition of user:injestEvent/1 overrides weak import from module
Warning: /Users/pmoura/Desktop/state.pl:3:
    Local definition of user:justAfter/2 overrides weak import from module
Warning: /Users/pmoura/Desktop/state.pl:4:
    Local definition of user:actorOfEvent/2 overrides weak import from module
Warning: /Users/pmoura/Desktop/state.pl:5:
    Local definition of user:objectOfEvent/2 overrides weak import from module
true.
```

Although these are **warnings** and not errors, calling the `inside/3` predicate **will** not give you what you want:

```
?- inside(Food,Eater,T).
true.
```

Where are the bindings?!? Let's trace the call to highlight the cause:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- inside(Food,Eater,T).
   Call: (8) module:inside(_2508, _2510, _2512) ? creep
   Call: (9) module:isTime(_2512) ? creep
   Exit: (9) module:isTime(_2512) ? creep
   Call: (9) module:injestEvent(_2804) ? creep
   Exit: (9) module:injestEvent(_2804) ? creep
   Call: (9) module:justAfter(_2512, _2806) ? creep
   Exit: (9) module:justAfter(_2512, _2806) ? creep
   Call: (9) module:actorOfEvent(_2804, _2510) ? creep
   Exit: (9) module:actorOfEvent(_2804, _2510) ? creep
   Call: (9) module:objectOfEvent(_2804, _2508) ? creep
   Exit: (9) module:objectOfEvent(_2804, _2508) ? creep
   Exit: (8) module:inside(_2508, _2510, _2512) ? creep
true.
```

The trace makes it clear that the "state" predicates are being called in the **wrong** context.

A clean solution is to use Logtalk objects instead of Prolog modules. Logtalk extends Prolog and supports most systems, including SWI-Prolog. It supports interfaces/protocols as first-class entities (which solve the first problem you mention) and supports inheritance and calling predicates in their usage context (which solves the second problem). You could use e.g.

```
----- common.lgt -----
:- object(common).

:- public([
    inside/3, isTime/1, injestEvent/1, justAfter/2, actorOfEvent/2, objectOfEvent/2
]).

inside(Food,Eater,T) :-
    % call the next predicates in "self", i.e. in the
    % object that received the inside/3 message
    ::isTime(T),
    ::injestEvent(InjEvent),
    ::justAfter(T,InjEvent),
    ::actorOfEvent(InjEvent, Eater),
    ::objectOfEvent(InjEvent, Food).

:- end_object.
----------------------
```

and then represent "state" as:

```
----- state.lgt -----
:- object(state, extends(common)).

isTime(1).
injestEvent(injEvent).
justAfter(1, injEvent).
actorOfEvent(injEvent, eater).
objectOfEvent(injEvent, food).

:- end_object.
---------------------
```

A quick test (after installing Logtalk):

```
$ swilgt
...
?- {common, state}.
...
true.

?- state::inside(Food,Eater,T).
Food = food,
Eater = eater,
T = 1.
```

As a bonus, you can define as many "state" objects as you need. You can also have *default definitions* for the "state" predicates in the `common` object. These will be inherited and used when the "state" objects don't provide a definition for a particular predicate. For example, let's add to `common` the clause:

```
objectOfEvent(injEvent, drink).
```

and delete (or comment out) the clause `objectOfEvent(injEvent, food).` from `state`. Save and reload and retrying the query will give you:

```
?- {*}.   % abbreviation for Logtalk's make
% Redefining object common
...
% Redefining object state
...
true.

?- state::inside(Food,Eater,T).
Food = drink,
Eater = eater,
T = 1.
```

If needed, you can also dynamically create new state objects instead of defining them in source files. For example:

```
?- create_object(s2, [extends(common)], [], [isTime(42), ...]).
```

This *may not be* the answer you were looking for but this is also the case where the best answer is to use the right tool^H^H^H^H encapsulation mechanism for the job. Your programming pattern is also a quite common one (and one of the reasons Logtalk was developed).

Comment: Logtalk is wonderful- I'm a beginner to Prolog and wanted to keep things simple, but this got things going and seems ideal for my task.

Thanks for your detailed reply Paulo

Comment: Also got to advise people to look at this similar question: the ^^ syntax is a life saver! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697056/prolog-design-pattern-to-extend-module-predicates#32720952

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple to add a basic form of 'object orientation'.
Let's say we have a clause in a module logic:

```
:- module(logic, [inside/4]).

% apply the rule to a specified module (expected to be a state object)
inside(M,Food,Eater,T) :-
    M:isTime(T),
    M:injestEvent(InjEvent),
    M:justAfter(T, InjEvent),
    M:actorOfEvent(InjEvent, Eater),
    M:objectOfEvent(InjEvent, Food).
```

and we have a lot of state objects pertinent: in a file state1.pl

```
isTime(10).
injestEvent(eat).
justAfter(10, eat).
actorOfEvent(eat, mick).
objectOfEvent(eat, food).
```

and in a file state2.pl

```
isTime(20).
injestEvent(sleep).
justAfter(20, sleep).
actorOfEvent(sleep, everyone).
objectOfEvent(sleep, dream).
```

then a possible session:

```
?- [logic].
true.

?- s1:consult(state1).
true.

?- s2:consult(state2).
true.

?- inside(s1,Food,Eater,T).
Food = food,
Eater = mick,
T = 10.

?- inside(s2,What,Who,T).
What = dream,
Who = everyone,
T = 20.
```

A small generalization, worth to try:

```
inside(M,Food,Eater,T) :-
    resolve(M),
    M:isTime(T),
    ...
```

where resolve/1 could be

```
resolve(M) :- var(M) -> current_module(M), catch(M:isTime(_),_,fail) ; true.
```

this trick enable 'browsing the objects':

```
?- inside(M,X,Y,Z).
M = s2,
X = dream,
Y = everyone,
Z = 20 ;
M = s1,
X = food,
Y = mick,
Z = 10 ;
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to CapelliC is the use of [Prolog dicts](http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/10_docu/05_frequent/07_theories/10_advanced/06_func.html). They have been introduced by SWI-Prolog and since release 1.3.0 they are also available in Jekejeke Prolog. If the receiver is not needed, one can simply use an underscore.

**File state1.pl:**

```
:- module(state1, [isTime/2, injestEvent/2, justAfter/3, 
                   actorOfEvent/3, objectOfEvent/3]).
:- reexport(logic).
_.isTime() := 10.
_.injestEvent() := eat.
_.justAfter(10) := eat.
_.actorOfEvent(eat) := mick.
_.objectOfEvent(eat) := food.
```

**File state2.pl:**

```
:- module(state2, [isTime/2, injestEvent/2, justAfter/3, 
                   actorOfEvent/3, objectOfEvent/3]).
:- reexport(logic).
_.isTime() := 20.
_.injestEvent() := sleep.
_.justAfter(20) := sleep.
_.actorOfEvent(sleep) := everyone.
_.objectOfEvent(sleep) := dream.
```

**File logic.pl:**

```
:- module(logic, [inside/4]).
M.inside(Food,Eater) := T :-
    T = M.isTime(),
    InjEvent = M.injestEvent(),
    InjEvent = M.justAfter(T),
    Eater = M.actorOfEvent(InjEvent),
    Food = M.objectOfEvent(InjEvent).
```

To make the logic also visible in state1 and state2 use reexport/1. This allows sending a message to state1 or state2, but nevertheless a method from logic will be processed. Here is an example run:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.7.19)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- T = state1{}.inside(Food,Eater).
T = 10,
Food = food,
Eater = mick.

?- T = state2{}.inside(Food,Eater).
T = 20,
Food = dream,
Eater = everyone.
```

The exports of isTime/2, injestEvent/2, etc.. will go away with the upcoming release 1.3.1 of Jekejeke Prolog when we have made ('.')/3 call-site aware. But the result for Jekejeke Prolog is the same:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.0
(c) 1985-2018, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- T = state1{}.inside(Food,Eater).
T = 10,
Food = food,
Eater = mick

?- T = state2{}.inside(Food,Eater).
T = 20,
Food = dream,
Eater = everyone
```

Comment: For a function on Prolog dicts, that also demonstrates non-determinism see also this example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52582049/502187